# Performing Theil-Sen regression on raster data by R software

Tags: raster, r, slope

I have seven NDVI raster layers (in ERDAS img format) of an area. Each NDVI layer is the peak growing time of that year. I want to do trend analysis of NDVI values change over the years pixel by pixel. The seven time variables (years) are 1985, 1990, 1994, 1999, 2004, 2010, 2014. My intension is to use the Theil-Sen regression on the seven raster NDVI layers to get four raster outputs - slope, significance, adjusted significance and offset. Using the raster outputs, I will be able to generate a synthetic NDVI layer for any year in the time frame (for example 2007), which will help me for my further analysis.

- Is there any way to get the four raster outputs (slope, sig, adj sig and offset) from the seven raster NDVI layers using Theil-Sen regression in R software?
- If yes, what would be the potential package to be used?
- What could be the potential code there for a less time consuming processing? I'm new in R.

Comment: Could you click 'edit' and provide more context? What does the Theil-Sen estimator do? What format of raster data do you have, and what are the variables involved?

Comment: I answered a similar question in researchgate. You can use `zyp.sen()` function from the `zyp` package. Here is a [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zyp/zyp.pdf) to the documentation; Also you can use `getValues` from the `raster` package to retrieve the raster's values to a data.frame.

Comment: @Simba The [Theil-Sen estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theil%E2%80%93Sen_estimator) is a standard robust nonparametric method to estimate a slope in a linear regression with one independent variable. Because the question is `R` based, the format of the raster is immaterial--you might as well assume it is stored as an `R` matrix or array object. RSGIS: What exactly do you mean by "adjusted significance"? Adjusted for what? And would the "offset" be an estimate of the intercept?

Comment: Adjusted significance is the adjusted p-value. Yes, offset is the intercept.

Comment: Adjusting for what? Multiple comparisons? If so, what is your plan to model spatial correlation and its influence on the overall false positive rate?

Comment: The raster.kendall function in the spatialEco package does exactly what you are  after. The slope raster is the Theil-Sen slope.